# Android web service access

Tags: java, android, web-services, apache-axis, ksoap2

I have accessed a web service from Android 2.2.It is perfectly OK.I changed my program for Android 4.0.3 to access same web service.But this doesn't work.
Code of my Android program

```
 import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class AndroidWSClientActivity extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.android4.com/";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "sayHello";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.android4.com/sayHello/";
private static final String URL = "http://175.157.45.91:8085/ForAndroid4/services/TestWs?wsdl";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

         HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
         final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
         final String str = response.toString();

         runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){

          public void run() {
              TextView result;
               result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               result.setText(str);
              }
           }

          } 

   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  };
}
}
```

I have added internet permission also. 
This program installing on emulator correctly. But doesn't show the result. No any errors showing.Eclipse says that "networkThread" is not used. How can I correct this ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never started the networkThread.  You would need this at the very end of your onCreate():

```
networkThread.start();
```

That being said, you would do well to use AsyncTask to do this type of thing.  I think you will find it much easier once you get the hang of it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html